# How to stop MySQL80 service from running on startup?

Tags: mysql, windows-services

I was having an issue with starting the MySQL module on XAMPP. This issue stopped after going to the Services application on Windows and stopping the mysql80 service. (I have MySQL Workbench installed.)

Is there a way to prevent mysql80 service from running on Windows startup?

Comment: If you run cmd as admin you can enter - sc config "mysql80" start=disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Services application, go to the mysql80 row and double click. Change Startup Type to Manual.